# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, monodevelop

I am writing a simple Xamarin application with MvvmCross. I just tried to do some binding but compliler is giving me this error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.CreateBindingSet(TTarget)' and
>   'MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.CreateBindingSet(TTarget)** . This error is thrown at   `var set =
>   this.CreateBindingSet<LoginViewController, LoginViewModel>();`

I have added MvvmCross, MvvmCross.Binding, MvvmCross.Platform and MvvmCross.Core in my Xamarin.iOS project.

Please help to get rid of this error. Below is the code of my ViewController:

```
using Kinettix.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views;
using UIKit;

namespace Kinettix.iOS.Views
{
    public partial class LoginViewController : MvxViewController<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginViewController() : base("LoginViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            this.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;


            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginViewController, LoginViewModel>();
            set.Apply();

            tfUsername.ShouldReturn+= (sender) =>
            {
                sender.ResignFirstResponder();
                return false;
            };

            tfPassword.ShouldReturn += (sender) =>
            {
                sender.ResignFirstResponder();
                return false;
            };


        }



        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, that should work. One thing that usually is different is: base(nameof(LoginViewController), null), instead of passing the string. But not sure it will solve the issue.

Comment: Changed to base(nameof(LoginViewController), null); but did not solve the problem.

Comment: Whats the version number for you MvvmCross.Platform package? And is the LoginViewModel bound to any other ViewController, and do you have multiple LoginViewModels?

Comment: Version is 5.7.0 and loginViewModel is not bound to any other ViewController. I have only one LoginViewController.

Comment: And whats the version number of the other nuget packages-MvvmCross, MvvmCross.Binding, and MvvmCross.Core? Ok so you have only one LoginViewController, and do you have multiple LoginViewModels?

Comment: MvvmCross is 6.3.0, MvvmCross.Binding 5.7.0, Core 5.7.0. Only have one LoginViewController and one LoginViewModel. Strange thing is : If I add these binding lines in other viewmodels,  I get the same error.

Comment: :) Exactly why i was asking those questions. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have found the answer to my question. I had MvvmCross.Core, MvvmCross.Platform, MvvmCross.binding and MvvmCross in my iOS project. It was complaining about ambiguous call to CreateBindingSet between MvvmCross and MvvmCross.Binding. I removed all packages and just installed MvvmCross. This way, It made call to CreateBindingSet using MvvmCross and It Worked. :)